# CIFAR-10 can't get above 10% Accuracy with MobileNet/VGG16 on Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train the mobileNet and VGG16 models with the CIFAR10-dataset but the accuracy can't get above 9,9%. I need it with the completly model (include_top=True) and without the wights from imagenet.

P.S.: I have tried increasing/decreasing dropout and learning rate and I changed the optimizers but I become always the same accuracy.

```
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
                                    rotation_range=2, 
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    zoom_range=.1 )
val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
                                    rotation_range=2, 
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    zoom_range=.1)

train_generator.fit(x_train)
val_generator.fit(x_val)


batch_size= 100
epochs=50

learn_rate=.001

sgd=SGD(lr=learn_rate,momentum=.9,nesterov=False)
adam=Adam(lr=learn_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)

model_1.compile(optimizer=adam,loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.fit_generator(train_generator.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=batch_size),
                      epochs=epochs,
                      steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]//batch_size,
                      validation_data=val_generator.flow(x_val,y_val,batch_size=batch_size),validation_steps=250,
                      verbose=1)
```

Results of MobileNet:

```
    Epoch 1/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 50ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1021
Epoch 2/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1030
Epoch 3/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1016
Epoch 4/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1014
Epoch 5/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1040
Epoch 6/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1009
Epoch 7/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1035
Epoch 8/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1013
Epoch 9/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1029
Epoch 10/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1023
Epoch 11/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1017
Epoch 12/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1020
Epoch 13/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1020
Epoch 14/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1033
Epoch 15/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1011
Epoch 16/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1016
Epoch 17/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1024
Epoch 18/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1024
Epoch 19/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1041
Epoch 20/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1010
Epoch 21/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1022
Epoch 22/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1014
Epoch 23/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1035
Epoch 24/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1032
Epoch 25/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 26/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1018
Epoch 27/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1022
Epoch 28/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1031
Epoch 29/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1022
Epoch 30/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1015
Epoch 31/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1028
Epoch 32/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1015
Epoch 33/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1030
Epoch 34/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1003
Epoch 35/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1044
Epoch 36/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 37/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1022
Epoch 38/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1021
Epoch 39/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1028
Epoch 40/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 41/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1035
Epoch 42/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1009
Epoch 43/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1034
Epoch 44/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1024
Epoch 45/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1016
Epoch 46/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1028
Epoch 47/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1016
Epoch 48/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1033
Epoch 49/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1018
Epoch 50/50
350/350 [==============================] - 17s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1023

<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fa30b188e48>
```

Is there any solution to solve this?

Comment: Can you show us the model code, how you created it ?

Comment: I’m guessing the layers are not set to be trainable

Comment: @mujjiga I didn't create it I just imported it, The model is integrated in Keras.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren I really think so..

Comment: @mujjiga here: model_1 = MobileNet(include_top=True, weights=None, input_shape=(32,32,3), classes=y_train.shape[1])

Answer (score 0):

I use the MobileNet model often and it works well. To use it see the code below.

```
 
 mobile = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet( include_top=False,
                                                           input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3),
                                                           pooling='max', weights='imagenet',
                                                           alpha=1, depth_multiplier=1,dropout=.4)
  x=mobile.layers[-1].output
  x=keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
  predictions=Dense (len(classes), activation='softmax')(x)
  model = Model(inputs=mobile.input, outputs=predictions)    
  for layer in model.layers:
      layer.trainable=True
  model.compile(Adamax(lr=lr_rate), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Classes is the number of classes in the dataset. Image size is the size of the image in pixels.s

Comment: That's not the problem actually, with weights='imagenet' and include_top=False I achieve an accuracy of over 90% but I want to train the model without those parameters.

Comment: If you leave top=True your final layer will have as many classes as the original VGG16 model has which I believe is 1000. Perhaps that is why your loss is nan (not a number) I haven't looked but I believe the CIFAR10 data set does not have 1000 classes. You have to tailor the top layer to have as many nodes as you have  classes.

Comment: Thought about it a bit more. I suppose it is possible for the network to learn with frozen random weights. with top=False. Thr VGG network will be applying a fixed transform to each image and perhaps the dense layers can still learn.